How to Implement Live Tracking Background Service with Firebase in Flutter?
I am trying to implement a background service for live tracking in my Flutter application that works on both Android and iOS. The app is supposed to update the user's location data to Firebase Firestore periodically when the user clicks the "Start Service" button.
I am using the flutter_background_service package along with Firebase for this purpose. However, I am encountering the following error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

Despite initializing Firebase in the main() method, I am still getting the error mentioned above. It seems like Firebase is not properly initialized in the background isolate.
Code Snippet:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initializeService();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
Future<void> initializeService() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: false,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true,
      onForeground: onStart,
    ),
  );
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); // Is this the correct way to initialize Firebase in the background?
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) async {
    if (service is AndroidServiceInstance && await service.isForegroundService()) {
      callBacFunction();
    }
  });
}

void callBacFunction() async {
  final locationData = {
    'latitude': Random().nextInt(100),
    'longitude': Random().nextInt(100),
    'timestamp': DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
  };
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('live_tracking')
      .doc("1122")
      .set(locationData, SetOptions(merge: true));
}

How can I properly initialize Firebase for use in a background service?
Is flutter_background_service the best option for live tracking, or should I consider other packages?
How do I ensure the background service works seamlessly on both Android and iOS?
Any guidance or suggestions are much appreciated. I have no experience with background services, so detailed steps would be helpful.
Thank you in advance!
